# reduce fsck time through lvm design considerations

Tags: redhat, lvm, fsck

I need to create two 9 TB file systems and i am struggling to design it. how does fsck work under the cover?

I have two options:
1. I create two 9TB LUNs at storage and create VG on them and then create LVs of 9TB each to create file system of 9TB each
2. I create 9 2TB LUNs at storage and create VG on them and then create LVs of 9TB each to create file system of 9TB each

what option from above will take less time for fsck to run regularly and during boot?

Answer (score 1):

Though there maybe some small difference there shouldn't be much.  A run of fsck mostly depends on the filesystem in use, and the contents of the filesystem.  The partitioning of the underlying block devices doesn't real make any difference to fsck specifically.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the lvm design is going to affect the time it takes for fsck the filesystem. Better to use a filesystem that is fast at doing fsck (ie ext4 over ext3, ...)